# Android Phone taking up more space than it should

Tags: internal-storage, htc, htc-one

I have a relatively new HTC ONE M8 running Android 5.0.1 (according to the settings page).

The phone is supposed to have 10.5 GB space according to Windows, but at the moment only 945 MB is free (again, according to Windows). However, when I select all of my files within and check properties it shows that they all take up only 5 GB of space, meaning another 4-5ish has disappeared. Any ideas how to fix this, as I'm trying to free up space for more music and pictures?

[image]

[image]

Screenshots from DiskInfo and DiskUsage:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Added screenshots to my question. The ~5GB music is correct, so I assume my apps are taking up all the space? Is there a way to completely erase all apps and their data, and then redownload the ones I paid for, for free?

Comment: You can use factory reset to remove all the third-party apps and any app's data. Alternatively, you may go to Settings -> Apps, and uninstall or "clear data" for the apps you wish for.

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems it could be (or a combination of):

1. The stock software is massively huge and HTC has a problem that an update will fix.
2. An app you've downloaded has installed Bloatware and clogged up your storage.
3. An app you've downloaded assumed you wanted to download other things (photos, videos, etc) without telling you.

I'd advise [Storage Analyzer & Disk Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile_infographics_tools.mydrive) to determine exactly what it is that is taking all that space. Happy hunting!

Answer (score 0):

## Windows is wrong; DiskUsage is right

Based on your question, and on the comments on the question:  It is clear that Windows cannot see all the information stored on your phone, but that [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) can see it all.

## You need not do anything yet

> I'm trying to free up space for more music and pictures

You still have 1 GB free. If this remains true forever, it's no problem.

I suggest keeping an eye on your free space.

Once your free space falls to about 500 MB, you'll be unable to install new apps. I think you may also be unable to upgrade existing apps.

Once you become unable to upgrade existing apps, it's definitely wise to take action. This is because it's wise to always keep security-sensitive apps (such as Chrome and WebView) up to date.

## Buying a MicroSD card

Because your phone has a MicroSD card slot, consider buying and installing a MicroSD card and moving some stuff (music?) from your phone to the card. This will cost you money but may save you time.

#### Choosing a MicroSD card

[Another thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219775/how-to-choose-which-microsd-card-to-buy-for-your-android-device) provides advice on how to buy a good (non-counterfeit) MicroSD card for your phone.

## OS upgrades

Perhaps you can upgrade your phone to an operating system which supports "adoptable storage". Such operating systems include:

- Android 6.0 "Marshmallow",
- or CyanogenMod 13.0 "Marshmallow",
- or LineageOS 13.0 "Marshmallow",
- or better.

Certain other "custom ROMs" also support "adoptable storage".

I do not know whether your phone supports any of these operating systems. I have not checked. To find out, you can do a Google search, or you can post another question.

If you can do such an upgrade, consider doing so before you insert the card for the first time. The operating system will offer to reformat the card for adoptable storage.

#### Upgrade warning

Before upgrading your operating system, and especially before switching operating systems, I strongly recommend that you back up all your data. You can back it up to the cloud or elsewhere.